# LSTM CNN training and test accuracy are same with low prediction probability

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have written a code in python to label an unstructured text into one of the 12 labels from 0 to 11. The code is an LSTM CNN model but the train and test accuracy are same. When I predict on the model, the probability that the unstructured text falls into one of the 12 categories seems to be very low. I am unable to find an explanation as to why this is happening. I have browsed for an answer, but most of the online solutions seem to be difficult to interpret since I am a beginner in python and neural networks.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
import pandas as pd
from keras.preprocessing import text as keras_text, sequence as keras_seq
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, LSTM, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Dropout, Activation


#Preparing training data
raw = pd.read_fwf(Trainset)
xtrain_obfuscated = pd.read_fwf(Trainset_x)
ytrain = pd.read_fwf(Trainset_y,header=None)
xtrain_obfuscated['label']=ytrain[0]
xtrain_obfuscated.rename(columns={0:'text'}, inplace=True)

#Reading test file
xtest_obfuscated = pd.read_fwf(testset,header=None)
xtest_obfuscated.rename(columns={0:'text'}, inplace=True)

#One-hot encoding on training data
xtrain_encoded = pd.get_dummies(xtrain_obfuscated, columns=['label'])

#df_encoded_copy=df_encoded.copy()

#List sentences train
#Text matrix to be fed into neural network
train_sentence_list = xtrain_encoded["text"].fillna("unknown").values
list_classes = ["label_0","label_1","label_2",'label_3',"label_4","label_5","label_6","label_7","label_8","label_9","label_10","label_11"]
y = xtrain_encoded[list_classes].values

#List sentences test
test_sentence_list = xtest_obfuscated["text"].fillna("unknown").values

max_features = 20000
maxlen = raw[0].map(len).max()
batch_size=32

#Sequence Generation
tokenizer = keras_text.Tokenizer(char_level = True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(train_sentence_list))
# train data
train_list_tokenized = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_sentence_list)
X = keras_seq.pad_sequences(train_list_tokenized, maxlen=maxlen)

X_train, X_valid= train_test_split(X, test_size=0.2)
y_train, y_valid= train_test_split(y, test_size=0.2)
# test data
test_list_tokenized = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_sentence_list)
X_test = keras_seq.pad_sequences(test_list_tokenized, maxlen=maxlen)
#Model
embedding_vector_length = 128
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, embedding_vector_length, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)
#cross_val_score(model, X_train, y, cv=3)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_valid, y_valid, verbose=0)
#print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
a = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Also, I am not sure of the use of max_features = 20000. What does it do here and how should its value be set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: change

```
model.add(Dense(12, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

to

```
model.add(Dense(12, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As **R. Giskard** suggested, if there are more than 2 classes, the `sigmoid` activation could indeed be changed to `softmax` (which would give you outputs summing up to 1), and `binary_crossentropy` should be switched to `categorical_crossentropy`. `binary_crossentropy` - as the name suggests - is designed for binary classification problems.

As for the poor accuracy within a single class, there could be a number of reasons. The most obvious one could be the dataset balance - is there about the same amount of training samples in the problematic class as in the others? Analyze your data first before trying to build the classifiers.

Also, you seem to be starting with a rather complex model with your own character embeddings on top of that. Have you tried a simpler approach first to get a better feel of the data? Something like TF-IDF to vectorize the data and an easier to interpret classifier such as a random forest model. If a simpler model is able to solve your problem, there's no need for custom NN architectures. You could start with a library such as the `scikit-learn` and perform some basic tests to better understand the data before deciding to use deep learning. Especially since DL models generally require significant training sets to reach good results.

In fact, you probably shouldn't be building your custom embeddings or a model from scratch at all. Using prebuilt models such as [FastText](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html) or BERT will likely yield much better results.